# Использование спецсимволов html в jsx

Tags: jsx, символы

Заполняю графу погоды в приложении. Данные приходят с api, соответственно, пишу конструкцию на случай, если данные не придут. Проблема в том, что значок градуса поставлен спецсимволом, а нужно, чтобы он скрывался, пока данных нет.

Если сделать как внизу, то он выводится строкой, а не символом.

```
<span>
   {weatherData.main ? `${Math.ceil(weatherData?.main?.temp)}&deg`: '-'};
</span>
```